# Facebook api for Iphone sign in and sign out

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate facebook api into my application, I have read the documentation of facebook and there is a login button which takes me out of application and log me in by facebook applicatio or facebook mobile site and then throw me back to my application. My question is can i authenticate user within my application. And if yes then please guide me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you can try this:

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];

[FBSession setActiveSession:session];

[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                        FBSessionState status,
                        NSError *error) {

    }];
```

This should open WebView which will allow you to perform login within the app.

To log user out it is enough to do so:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```